# HQL with multiple tables joining and sum(), first()

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Talbes:

```
Grandpa
    GP_ID  (PK)
    NAME

Dad
    DAD_ID (PK)
    PG_ID  (FK)

Children
    C_ID   (PK)
    DAD_ID (FK)
    MONEY_AMOUNT
    MONEY_UNIT
```

Class (annotations omitted here):

```
class Grandpa
{
    Long id;
    String name;

    Double moneyAmount; // sum of Children's money amount

    String moneyUnit; // first of Children's money unit.
}

class Dad
{
    Long id;
    Grandpa grandpa;
}

class Children
{
    Long id;
    Dad dad;

    Double moneyAmount;
    String moneyUni;
}
```

I want to write a hql to get the Grandpa objects with sum(grandpa.dad.children.money_amount) and first(grandpa.dad.children.money_unit). Here is mine but it doesn't work:

```
select gp, sum(chdn.moneyAmount) as gp.moneyAmount, first(chdn.moneyUnit) as gp.moneyUnit
from Grandpa gp, Dad dad, Children chdn
where gp.id =: chdn.dad.grandpa.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select gp.id, gp.name, sum(chdn.moneyAmount) as moneyAmount, min(chdn.moneyUnit) as gp.moneyUnit
from Children chdn, chdn.dad dad, dad.grandpa gp
groupBy gp.Id
```

and using a aliastobean transformer to project into the grandpa dto

Or you implement moneyAmount and unit as properties which access a children collection containing the dads and sum the amounts in memory then it would be

```
select gp from Grandpa gp join fetch gp.children dad join fetch dad.children
```

but beware of gigantic cartesian products

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'm trying it right now. 2 questions about your HQL:
1. The dad doesn't have field "Children". So there is no "dad.Children".
2. If there are many fields in the Grandpa, must I list all of them in the HQL?

Comment: And when I tried it, there is an exception about the line 1, the point "." in "as gp.moneyAmount". Is there anything wrong in it?

Comment: Since there may be some Grandpa doesn't have children (Dad) or the Dad may not have children (Children), I think I should use left out join but I don't know how to modify it with outer join. Could you please help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can not use left outer join in the hql when gp and dad don't have a children collection. You Options: **1.** you could issue a second query fetching all gp which are not returned by the first query and initialise the amount and unit to the default value **2.** introduce children collections **3.** use an sql query to do what you want and use aliastobean to transform the results into the object